# How to update datatable with formatStyle via dataTableProxy

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am trying to update the `backgroundColor` of a column using a `dataTableProxy`. However, I am not sure of how to properly handle the column names. Here's an example :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(
       DT::dataTableOutput("myplot")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$myplot <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(as.data.frame(rnorm(5))) %>%
            formatStyle(1, backgroundColor = 'red')
    })

    proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("myplot")
    mycolors <- c("red", "green", "blue")

    observe({
        invalidateLater(1000)

        proxy %>% replaceData(as.data.frame(rnorm(5)))

        # proxy %>% replaceData(as.data.frame(rnorm(5))) %>%
        #     formatStyle(1, backgroundColor = sample(mycolors, 1))
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Even though the numbers update as I would expect, I can't get the `formatStyle` to work (commented out code). It keeps showing the following error :

> ```
> Warning: Error in !: invalid argument type
>   56: name2int
> ```

And here's the error I get using `"rnorm(5)"` as column when calling `formatStyle`.

> ```
> Warning: Error in name2int: You specified the columns: rnorm(5), but the column names of the data are 
>   57: stop
> ```

What is the correct way of referencing the columns when using the `dataTableProxy` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not based on the column names.
`formatStyle` doesn't take a proxy object as an argument, it expects a table object created by `datatable()`.

See `?dataTableProxy` for   the functions available to manipulate existing datatable instances. Accordingly you cannot directly change the backgroundcolor via a dataTableProxy.

However, one of the functions available to deal with proxy objects is `replaceData()` which you are using above. Furthermore, `formatStyle` gives us the possibility to set the backgroundcolor **based on the data available in the table**.

Accordingly you can create a helper column (and dynamically change it) holding the information for your background color, hide it and tell `formatStyle` to change the color according to that coulmn.

Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("myplot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  mycolors <- c("red", "green", "blue")
  
  output$myplot <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DF <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(rnorm(5), 10, rep = TRUE)), "background_color" = sample(mycolors, 1))
    HideCols <- which(names(DF) %in% c("background_color"))
    datatable(DF, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=HideCols)))) %>% formatStyle(
      "background_color",
      target = "row",
      backgroundColor = styleEqual(levels = mycolors, values = mycolors)
    )
  })
  
  proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("myplot")
  
  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    DF <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(rnorm(5), 10, rep = TRUE)), "background_color" = sample(mycolors, 1))
    proxy %>% replaceData(DF)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

[image: Result]

For further information please see [this](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html).